# how to override the toString method of an enum in dart

Tags: dart, enums

I'm just wondering if it's possible to override the `toString` method in dart
this is what I have:

```dart
enum Style{italic, bold, underline}
Style.italic.toString() 
// print Style.italic, but I want it to be just italic
```

Answer (score 14):

It's not currently possible to override methods of `enum`s.

Edit: It will be possible from Dart 2.17, where the ["enhanced enums" feature](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/enhanced-enums/feature-specification.md) is planned to be released (if all goes well).

At that point, you will be able to declare methods on `enum` declarations, and override `toString`.

So, you'd be able to do:

```dart
enum Style {
  italic, bold, underline;

  @override
  String toString() => this.name; 
}
```

to get what you ask for.
The `name` getter on enum values was added in Dart 2.15.

Comment: You are completely right,  As a workaround we can use extension Method the only issue is that we have to give another name to the custom `toString` method this is an example:
`extension StyleExtension on Style{ String describe() => toString().split('.').last;}`

Comment: If that's your use-case, we are trying to add  a `name` extension getter on enum values in an upcoming version of the Dart SDK. Not there yet.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.name` extension like `MyEnum.value.name`.

```dart
enum Style { italic, bold, underline }

void main(List<String> args) {
  print(Style.italic.name); // italic
}
```

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=599953520d582ec4d676864634557843)

Comment: I am using `dart v:2.16.1`